# Manual modification of binary AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, android-manifest

When using protocol buffers to deserialize the AndroidManifest.xml inside an Android aab file, I noticed a parameter "resource_id" which contains values that I could not find in any of the xml files under the res/values subfolder.

```
      attribute {
        namespace_uri: "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        name: "label"
        value: "@string/app_name"
        source {
          line_number: 11
        }
        resource_id: 16842753
        compiled_item {
          ref {
            id: 2131623963
            name: "string/app_name"
          }
        }
      }
```

I am trying to manually modify an aab file (including inserting new entries or modifying existing entries in the manifest file) and if these "resource_id" parameters are not defined, somehow the installation will not work properly.

My questions are

1. What are these "resource_id" and "id" parameters and how are their values defined? If I am manually modifying the manifest file, how to I generate them?
2. Some parameters such as `value: "@string/app_name"` has a "@" character in them. When I was manually reserializing a manifest file and manually added such a string, the output manifest file will contain a string that tries to escape the "@" character `value: "\@string/app_name"`. However, I don't see this problem when it is Android Studio that creates these parameters. How do I resolve this?

This is related to my other question that I asked earlier ([Similar apktool functionality for Android aab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66981728/similar-apktool-functionality-for-android-aab)).

Appreciate any advice on this.